# <link> with custom rel value or maybe a better way?

Tags: html, jquery

I'm trying to find a way to indicate in my webpage that I have one or more custom resources that are *related* to it so they can be downloaded and interpreted on page load/ready using jQuery. On the server side I have defined a file format similar to CSS that indicates attributes to be added to elements by jQuery selector, which is then translated to JSON for interpretation by the webpage.

The primary purpose of the custom resources is to have a way to tell the page what data binding rules to apply to its elements by jQuery selector, though I'm also curious about a more general solution since it could really apply to anything.

The best option I've been able to come up with so far is to include links to the resources as `<link>` elements in the page header like I would do with CSS resources. Since there isn't a predefined `rel` value that matches the type of data used in my resource files, I'd probably have to define a custom `rel` value.

After doing some research I've found that it is commonly discouraged to do anything that requires custom tags, attributes (save the `data-*` in HTML5), or values for standard fields (such as `rel`). More often than not the suggestions boil down to finding a "standard" way to achieve the desired result.

It makes sense that doing anything *non-standard* should be discouraged but I'm not really sure if there is a *standard* way to achieve what I am after here. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why reinvent wheels when you can use javascript with the `<script>` tag? You could point it to a server side script that will generate this javascript dynamically if needed.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - Forgive my ignorance here (I don't typically live in the web dev world), but are you suggesting that I create a `<script>` tag with a `src` pointing to my MVC action that returns a string formatted JSON object? That would work? If it does then I'll need to be able to reference from jquery somehow (since it isn't a literal javascript variable definition).

Comment: M.Babcock, you could point the `src` of a `script` tag to a controller action that will generate dynamic javascript. JSON is not javascript. So you will get a javascript error if you attempt to do that. But you could for example have the following in your dynamic script `var myvar = { foo: 'bar' };` and then you can use the `myvar` variable from other scripts. There might be better ways as well. It will depend on what you are trying to achieve and how you intend to use it.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - That's what I thought, but generating the javascript on my own sounds really dirty. This is part of a jquery extension that I'm working on to eliminate the need to specify the `data-bind` attribute on elements when using Kendo UI or Knockout (like KO's unobtrusive plugin only allowing explicit binding rather than conventions based). The goal would be to be able to specify a jquery selector to something like a `<link>` tag that would that would specify the URL of where to find the bindings (something like `$('link.data-bind').bind(bindingSource)`).

Comment: that's why you have JSON serializers on the server side => so that you don't have to do that manually (which indeed would have been extremely ugly and unsafe) and which allow you to serialize entire object graphs into JSON.

Comment: I have no problem with the serialization in C#, it's generating JS that I'm having trouble with. I'll play with it a bit and see what I can come up with. Thanks for your help.

Comment: For any future readers who are confused, JSON is JavaScript, not a 'custom' resource.

Comment: @TylerH That's not always accurate. JSON is data. JavaScript is code. It's reasonable that someone would want to load JSON as data into a page to be interpreted by a script expecting a JSON string. I've had a handful of cases in the last 10 years where this was needed, and I've since figured out the "right" way to do it. There are also other benefits of loading the JSON this way rather than using AJAX. Darin helped me get there

Comment: @M.Babcock As I am sure you know, the "JS" in JSON stands for JavaScript. That other languages can use or read JSON does not mean JSON stops being JavaScript; it has its origins there because that's what it is from.

Comment: @TylerH - As I'm sure _you_ know, JSON is a subset of JS used to represent JS data objects for transfer over the wire (among other things). It is not itself Java**Script** in that it is unable to represent functions or any directly executable or addressable code. It's like saying, _all thumbs are fingers but not all fingers are thumbs_.

Comment: @M.Babcock The *point* here is that JSON is a standard data notation format for use by JS (or other languages) and if someone knows JavaScript, they'll almost surely know JSON already. It is misleading to refer to it as a "custom resource" when it's a known/prescribed resource type in JS (and other languages) with built-in support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [Darin's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10049347/link-with-custom-rel-value-or-maybe-a-better-way/17691007#comment12858185_10049347), I've been able to dynamically populate a `<script>` tag with a server generated javascript (very simple javascript variable assignment to my server side JSON object). Unfortunately this isn't really the effect I'm after.

His suggestion did lead me to a less elegant alternative; rather than trying to use the `<link>` or other tags to identify where the maps for data-binding live, specify a single URL that returns a list of addresses and handle management of them server side. This is nice for me because I'm not really comfortable writing javascript (I'm a C# developer at the moment, though I've worn several other hats), but does feel like as elegant of a solution as could be possible.

I'll go with it for now but I'd be open to possible alternatives.